# Python3: Get count for same dictionaries within list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and want to get the unique dictionaries with count. i.e

```
[{'Basic': 100},
{'Basic': 100},
{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000},
{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000},
{'Basic': 100},
{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000},
{'Basic': 200}]
```

Out put should be like

```
{'Basic': 100} -> 3
{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000} -> 3
{'Basic': 200} -> 1

OR

[index_no] -> count
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: @quamrana i am just doing paper work till now in search for accurate and quick solution i posted here.

I just drive a solution with simple loop throw the list and compare them one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using collections.Counter

- Dictionary is not hashable so must convert each to a tuple
- Sort dictionary key, value pairs so initial order does not matter in each dictionary

**Code**

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [{'Basic': 100},
{'Basic': 100},
{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000},
{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000},
{'Basic': 100},
{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000},
{'Basic': 200}]

# Output count of each dictionary
Counter([tuple(sorted(d.items())) for d in lst])
```

**Output**

```
Counter({(('Basic', 100),): 3,
         (('Basic', 100), ('Food Allowance', 1000)): 3,
         (('Basic', 200),): 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution would be to loop over the list of dictionaries and save each unique one and keep a counter. Something like this:

```
def count_and_set_dict(dict):
    set_dict = []
    count_dict = []

    for d in dict:
        if d not in set_dict:
            set_dict.append(d)
            count_dict.append(1)
        else:
            count_dict[set_dict.index(d)] += 1

    for i in range(len(set_dict)):
        print(f"{set_dict[i]} --> {count_dict[i]}")

dicts = [{'Basic': 100},
{'Basic': 100},
{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000},
{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000},
{'Basic': 100},
{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000},
{'Basic': 200}]

count_and_set_dict(dicts)
```

Output

```
{'Basic': 100} --> 3
{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000} --> 3
{'Basic': 200} --> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach is getting unique dictionaries in the list and counting the elements in the original list by count()

```
dictlist = [{'Basic': 100},
{'Basic': 100},
{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000},
{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000},
{'Basic': 100},
{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000},
{'Basic': 200}]

unique_dictlist = list(map(dict, set(tuple(sorted(sub.items())) for sub in dictlist))) #to get only unique values.
for d in unique_dictlist:
    print(d,"-->",dictlist.count(d))
```

result:

```
{'Basic': 200} -> 1
{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000} -> 3
{'Basic': 100} -> 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter`, however, it requires the list elements to be hashable, which dictionaries are clearly not. One solution might be converting your dictionaries to 'string dictionaries':

```
from collections import Counter
Counter([str(i) for i in your_list])
```

will return:

```
Counter({"{'Basic': 100}": 3,
     "{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000}": 3,
     "{'Basic': 200}": 1})
```

or:

```
list(Counter(your_list).items())
```

will give

```
[("{'Basic': 100}", 3),
 ("{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000}", 3),
 ("{'Basic': 200}", 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

We must specify our purpose
There are different ways to do this

- If the order of the keys in each dictionary is the same, you can compare them
- If the order of the keys is not the same, you can arrange it
- If you don't want to sort, you can create a key with the values in it and compare the key

```
    b100
    b100
    b100f1000
    b100f1000
    b100
    b100f1000
    b100
```

Or use data classes(no need to order dict):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional

datas = [{'Basic': 100},
{'Basic': 100},
{'Basic': 100, 'FoodAllowance': 1000},
{'Basic': 100, 'FoodAllowance': 1000},
{'Basic': 100},
{'Basic': 100, 'FoodAllowance': 1000},
{'Basic': 200}]

@dataclass(order=True)
class BaseDataClass:
    Basic: int = None
    FoodAllowance: Optional[int] = None

objects = []
for data in datas:
    objects.append(BaseDataClass(**data))

print(objects[3]==objects[2])

from collections import Counter
Counter([str(object) for object in objects])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, my simple logic is to find the unique values using `set()` and then find out how many time it repeat using `.count()`.

More, I have convert dict values to string and convert again i am using ast package.

Code:

```
import ast
for i in set([str(d) for d in df1]):
    print(i + ' -> '+ str(df1.count(ast.literal_eval(i))))
```

Output:

```
{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000} -> 3
{'Basic': 100} -> 3
{'Basic': 200} -> 1
```

To dict:

```
import ast
tmp = {}
for i in set([str(d) for d in df1]):
    tmp[i] = df1.count(ast.literal_eval(i))
```

Output:

```
{"{'Basic': 100, 'Food Allowance': 1000}": 3,
 "{'Basic': 100}": 3,
 "{'Basic': 200}": 1}
```